# Can't use function return value in write context in

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have error message when i use this function:

```
$estadoSelect = empty(set_value('estado'))? 23 : set_value('estado');
```

i got this error

> Can't use function return value in write context in

Why?

Thanks

Comment: the same error appear. =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to PHP 5.5, `empty` expects a variable. As stated in [the docs](https://www.php.net/empty), passing the return value of a function will result in a parse error:

> Note:
>
> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: `empty(trim($name))`.
>
> Instead, `use trim($name) == false`.

You have to store your returned value in a variable.

```
$value = set_value('estado');
$estadoSelect = empty($value) ? 23 : set_value('estado');
```

You probably don't want `empty` in the first place. You should just check whether your variable is "falsy" and provide a default via `||`:

```
$estadoSelect = set_value('estado') || 23;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the PHP version you're running is minor than 5.5, the "empty" function expects exactly a variable, it does not support expression.

See: https://www.php.net/empty

From php.net:

> Note:
>
> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will
> result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work:
>
> empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.